# How to find the quotient of a rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been stuck on this problem because I don't know how to find the quotient of a rational expression.

$$\frac{x^4 - 1}{x + 1}$$

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  $x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)$.

Comment: $x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't see that, so the quotient would be x^3+x^2+x

Comment: @Pablo That is not quite right.  After you factor and cancel, you should have $(x - 1)(x^2 + 1)$.

Comment: I ended up having (x-1)($x^2$+1)
which simplifies to $x^3$-$x^2$ + x - 1

Comment: Have you at least tried something?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^4-1}{x+1}=\frac{x^4+x^3-x^3-1}{x+1}=x^3+\frac{-x^3-1}{x+1}=\dots$$
Just continue this process until no fraction is left. It may be instructive to Google "Polynomial long division".

Answer (score 1):

You can either do long polynomial division, or simply factor if you can. In this problem you can easily factor.

$$\frac{x^4-1}{x+1}=\frac{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)}{x+1}=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)}{(x+1)}=(x-1)(x^2+1)=x^3-x^2+x-1$$